# TcpClient bandwidth estimation

Tags: c#, networking, bandwidth, tcpclient

I want to create bandwidth estimation tools using TcpClient. The problem im having is, I want to perform measurement in predefined time (instead of predefine buffer data length to transfer). If i use loops(transfer small chunks of data repeatedly), wouldnt that slow down the performance(manual fragmentation vs auto fragmentation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you disable the Nagle algorithm. If you do, then yes, you'll be fragmenting things yourself. If you don't, you're unlikely to achieve your aim - because the data may not *actually* be written when you think it is... unless the other end of the connection sends back a final "ack" of course.

I would suggest you use a smallish sample to work out the rough speed, and then create a larger sample based on that, predicting how long it will take. You'd need to measure the time anyway - it's not like you're going to hit an *exact* predefined time - so it shouldn't make too much difference. You can always adjust the size as you go to some extent anyway - I'd anticipate that you'd end up sending plenty of packets unless it's a really slow network, so if you decide half way through to only send 200K instead of 300K, that shouldn't make much difference.

That may sound like your original suggestion, of course - but I'm only talking about sending "pretty large" chunks of data per call... say 16K. (Much bigger than the packet size, anyway.) That shouldn't affect fragmentation much, but will still allow you to tweak things somewhat as you go. I wouldn't advise you to send tiny, tiny packets.

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but i dont really understand. Correct me if im wrong. If i do disable nagle algorithm, i must manually fragment my data by repeatedly sends small chunks of data. if i dont disable nagle algorithm, my data will be auto fragmented. if i dont disable nagle algorithm, i am unlikely achieve my aim(bandwidth estimation?) because the sent data may not actually received when i thought it was received. kinda confused here.

Comment: @publicENEMY: I should clarify... if you can make the other end of the connection give you some value when it's received everything - effectively making the "ack" visible at the application level - then it would be okay... slightly inefficient in terms of the computing power at the sending side, but unlikely to be significant compared with network timing.

Comment: Here i thought tcp is reliable(guarantee correct data received). are saying that if i disable nagle, there is no guarantee that the sent data is received?

Comment: @publicENEMY: It's reliable in that while the stream is up, you'll get the data correctly and in order. But just because a "write" on the TcpClient has returned doesn't mean that the data has arrived at the other end yet. (And that's true regardless of whether or not you disable the Nagle algorithm, actually. It's just that without Nagle, each "write" will send the packet immediately.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jon Skeet. Much appreciated.

Comment: @publicENEMY: I hope it makes a certain amount of sense. This certainly isn't my clearest answer ever by a long chalk :) Anyway, no matter how bad the explanation is, I think my final advice is appropriate - use chunks which are large in comparison with packets, but small compared with the total amount of data you'll be transferring.